# vb.net 2010 Excel converting text fields to decimal

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am creating an excel object from a vb.net listview table simply by creating an array of F(x,y), creating a range and putting the values from the array in the range as follows.

```
 shXL.Range(Startcell,AEndCell).Value = F
```

However some of the fields are numeric and I want them to be formatted to two decimal places and EXCEL to recognize them as decimals

What I end up with in the excel worksheet is many green triangles telling me they are text fields.

How do I convert a range withing the sheet say A5,I20 to be formated as decimals.

I tried:  (x,y).numberformat = "00.00" which works to format to 2dp but still treats the cells as text.

Furthermore, is it possible to Excel Sum a range?  How is the possible?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Excel tries real hard not to interpret values that could be numeric as text.  How is the array `F` declared?  My crystal ball suggests that it is a `String(,)` in which you are getting exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shXL.Range(Startcell,AEndCell).Value = F

'// Loop over same range and convert to decimal
For Each cell In shXl.Range(Startcell,AEndCell)
    With cell
        .Value = CDec(.Value)
    End With
Next
```

> Furthermore, is it possible to Excel Sum a range? How is the possible?

I don't think Excel would have got very far as a spreadsheet product if it couldn't sum a range!

Assuming you want to do this in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) you need to use the instance of the application. I'll assume in your code it's `XL`

```
mySumValue = XL.WorksheetFunction.Sum(shXL.Range(Startcell,AEndCell))
```

Comment: Sorry I am new here.   Is that the Green Tick box to check?  I have checked so hopefully that's the answer